# Proving boundedness of a function .

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, linear-programming

Consider the function 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n) = \frac{\sum_{i}^{n}a_ix_i}{\sum_{i}^{n}b_ix_i}, 
\end{eqnarray}
over the set $S = \{x := (x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n):-1 \leq x_i \leq 1,\; \forall 1 \leq i \leq n,\; \sum_{i}^{n}b_ix_i \neq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i^{k}x_i = 0, 1 \leq x_i \leq m,  \}$. It is given that the vector $b:= (b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$ does not lie in the span of the vectors $c^{k}, 1 \leq k \leq m$.  Assume that the constants $(a_i, b_i, c_i^{k} ),  1 \leq i \leq n$,, $1 \leq k \leq m$ are all strictly positive. Is the function $f(x)$ bounded over the set $S$.

I am sorry for repeating this question twice (See Proving boundedness of a function (part 1)). I am trying to guess a sufficient condition to explain a numerical result I observed. 
In this particular question the counterexample made by @esoog should not be possible.

Comment: No, the set is not compact, as the set of vectors $x:\sum_{i}^{n}b_ix_i =0,-1 \leq x_i \leq 1 $ is closed. Hence the complement is not closed.

Comment: All right, my fault.

Comment: The set $\sum b_ix_i =0$ is closed implies the complement $\sum b_ix_i  \neq 0$ is open. Intersecting this open set with the the other constraints does not ensure that the set $S$ is closed.